# Is it possible for the Back button to take the user to a specific Activity given certain conditions, and behave like normal in other conditions?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'd like the back button to have behaviour similar to e.g.

```
// if I have an Item count > 1 and I'm not on ItemsListActivity
    // back button takes me to ItemsListActivity
// else
    // back button behaves like normal
```

Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do?

Comment: So why the downvote? Did my question displease someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Override `onBackPressed()`

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

So you could do something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (count > 1) && (!(this instanceof ItemsListActivity)) {
        // Launch ItemsListActivity / do whatever you want
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed(); // Do the normal back press functionality
    }
}
```

There is probably a better way to check what activity you are in!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible: you have to override onKeyDown:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the back button
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && itemCount > 1) {
        // Back button takes you to ItemsListActivity
        return true;
    }
    // Otherwise execute requested action
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

By the way, when user hit back, normally they expect to return on previous activity or exit app. IMHO it is better to make another way (button or menu item) to access on your ItemsListActivity.